# Where to keep default config file (app1name.yaml and application.yaml)in config server in case searchlocations = file:///tosomelocation/{profile}

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

I am trying some Spring cloud config server.
I have a scenerio.
if u provide searchlocations = file:///tosomelocation/{profile}
then u have to provide ur applications configuration  this way
Inside    **tosomelocation/dev**

```
     app1.yml
     app1-dev.yaml
     app2.yaml
     app2-dev.yaml
     application.yaml
```

But these configurations are picked by applications(app1 and app2) only when they run in dev PROFILE.

Now, If in int PROFILE too, i want app1.yml to be read, then where should i place this app1.yml file ???

right now i am placing app1.yaml in all profile specific folders

int folder

dev folder

e.t.c

Any help on this one ?

Comment: app1-int.yml? maybe

Comment: @spencergibb app1-int.yml is already there.It contains int specific configuration.
Whereas app1.yml is common for all environments.
and application.yaml is common for all applications.

Comment: That should work as is then

Comment: int/app1-int.yaml     int/app1.yaml
dev/app1-dev.yaml   dev/app1.yaml
prod/app1-prod.yaml  prod/app1.yaml

Here we can easily see app1.yaml is placed in int, dev and prod folders.
Is there anyplace in my scenerio where i can place this app1.yaml only at common location.So that int,dev and prod all can easily refer without explicitly placing them in thsese folders